# (Serious) Dataset of paedophilic Youtube comments (or similar)?

Tags: data-request, nlp, text

I think it would be useful to create a model that tries to predict whether a youtube comment is paedophilic - maybe the model should also take into account the channel name/description/front image.

It's not an easy task but at the moment I'm just looking for data.

I know it's a sensitive topic - but does anyone know of a dataset out there with the characteristics I need?

Comment: What do you mean by paedophilic comments?

Comment: There's an abundancy of paedophilic Youtube users, who post messages in children's videos and saying things they shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

[Dataset Abusive YouTube Comment](https://zenodo.org/record/1479531#.Xxu0vZ4zbDd)

Sexually Abusive Comments and specific words collection from popular youtube videos such as music videos and cartoons (Peppa Pig)

---

[Trending YouTube Video Statistics and Comments](https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube)
Daily statistics (views, likes, category, comments+) for trending YouTube videos

The dataset includes data gathered from videos on YouTube that are contained within the trending category each day.

There are two kinds of data files, one includes comments and one includes video statistics. They are linked by the unique video_id field.

---

If you are interested to generate your own dataset the below article might be helpful.

[How to Build Your Own Dataset of YouTube Comments](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-dataset-of-youtube-comments-39a1e57aade)

[Collecting Comments with YouTube Data API](https://github.com/XWilliamY/custom_yt_comments_dataset)